# why can i reference a runtime dependency at compile time?

Tags: maven

Eclipse has no problems letting me import a class that is scoped at runtime. Why is this?

The said class is HibernateValidator which is runtime scope.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    localValidatorFactoryBean.setProviderClass(HibernateValidator.class);
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}
```

I think i've just realised that it's because maven adds dependencies to your classpath even if they are runtime scoped?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, this artifact is in the compile-time classpath of some other dependency in your POM.

Try executing `mvn dependency:tree`.